# How to Get Post Meta in .Js File

Tags: javascript, post-meta

i have post meta named 'product_price'. If this post meta is called in php it can be written:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_price', true); ?>
```

How to get this post meta 'product_price' in themedir/js/script.js file?

Please help me masters. thank you

Comment: no, my post meta in single.php. I want to call this post meta 'product_price' in my .js file

Comment: No it's not. Post meta isn't "in" a template. The linked answer and comments are what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript cannot directly call PHP functions...

We need JS as well as PHP

JS will send ajax request as soon as document is ready, you need to specify postid yourself..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'action': 'PriceAJAX', 'postid': 12345},
        success: function(response) {
            Price = response['Theme'];
    });
});
```

Once it is done, the PHP will kick in, and find the post meta for your specified ID...

```
function PriceAJAX(){
    $ID = $_POST['postid']
    $Price = get_post_meta($ID, 'product_price', true);
    
    $Data  = array('Price' => $Price);
    wp_send_json($Data);
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_PriceAJAX', 'PriceAJAX');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_PriceAJAX', 'PriceAJAX' );
```